# Move the magento product description with tabs under the 'add to card' button

Tags: magento

I need to place the product description with the tabs under the 'add to card' button and right next to the picture on my website.

Can someone tell me how I can manage this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Open up your theme's /catalog/product/view.phtml and work from there.

Comment: Thanks solved it by placing description div into cart div!

Answer (score -1):

Solved it, needed to move the description div into the cart div in view.phtml